# Shlokas : "MAYA is eternal" by using the word "MAYA"

Tags: scripture, vedas

Namaste. Are there any shlokas explaining that "MAYA is eternal" by using the word "MAYA"?

Comment: Maya or Prakriti(nature) is eternal and exists as long as for an individual jiva as long it is under the effect of Triguna Maya. Ascending Maya leads to Kaivalya Moksha.https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/14  'Gita 14.1 The total material substance, prakṛiti, is the womb. I impregnate it with the individual souls, and thus all living beings are born. O son of Kunti, for all species of life that are produced, the material nature is the womb, and I am the seed-giving Father.O mighty-armed Arjun, the material energy consists of three guṇas (modes)-sattva (goodness), rajas, and tamas'

Comment: Gita 14.25 Those who are alike in happiness and distress; who are established in the Self; who look upon a clod, a stone, and a piece of gold as of equal value; who remain the same amidst pleasant and unpleasant events; who are intelligent; who accept both blame and praise with equanimity; who remain the same in honor and dishonor; who treat both friend and foe alike; and who have abandoned all enterprises – they are said to have risen above the three guṇas.' Here I or Father or Seed is the Purusha or Self or Atman without which any body of material Maya is declared dead by people.

Comment: Hare Krishna, Radhanath Swami who is disciple of Swami Prabhupada said: "Maya is eternal. Manifestations of her are temporary, but maya is forever. She is Krsna’s external energy, the bahiranga shakti. She is forever. And when she gets her jaws around you, she will never let go for the rest of eternity until you surrender to Krsna, surrender to God." Source: https://www.radhanathswami.net/yearwise/2009/maya-wont-let-go-until-we-surrender-by-hh-radhanath-swami

Comment: Dear Manu Kumar and Hare Krsna, thank you so much. I need this paticular silokas just for discussion with scientists regarding to eternity of matter and energy as to General Relativity.